# FormatException C#

Tags: c#

so I'm currently taking a course on `C#` programming to get freshened up.

Turned out I forgot some important things!

```
namespace FitnessFrog
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int runningTotal = 0;

        bool keepGoing = true;

        while(keepGoing)
        {

            // Prompt the user for minutes exercised
            Console.Write("Enter how many minutes you exercised or type \"quit\" to exit: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input == "quit")
            {
                keepGoing = false;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    int minutes = int.Parse(input);
                    runningTotal = runningTotal + minutes;

                    if(minutes <= 0)
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine("Eh, what about actually exercising then?"); 
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(minutes <= 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Better than nothing, am I right?");
                    }
                    else if (minutes <= 24)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well done, keep working!");
                    }
                    else if (minutes <= 60)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An hour, awesome! Take a break, ok?");
                    }
                    else if (minutes <= 80)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Woah, remember to drink if you're going to exercise THAT long!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Okay, now you're just showing off!");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("You've exercised for " + runningTotal + " minutes");
                }
                    catch(FormatException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("That is not valid input");
                        continue;
                    }




                // Repeat until the user quits
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So I'm trying to make it say "This is not valid input" when you type a string instead of an integer.

Thanks in advance! `<3`

Comment: So... whats the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead for Parse, since it having internal exception handling mechanisms, And you can use it's return value(true/false)to check whether the operation is successful or not, for a successful conversion it will return true, and the return value for a failure conversion will be `false`

```
int minutes;

if(!int.TryParse(input,out minutes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("invalid input");
}
else
{
   // Proceed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`int minutes = int.Parse(input);` - you should use `TryParse()` instead of `Parse()`

```
int minutes;
bool parsed = int.TryParse(input, out minutes);
if (parsed)
{
    // your if statements
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not valid input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving input from your users, you will want to consider actually using the [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJ-ui_767MAhUpx4MKHftfCp0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.int32.tryparse(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFbXt3c2ISaw0dYAeLH9G7IRZ8PfA&sig2=CmsuMlwgcGKmATrCo6yoSQ&bvm=bv.120551593,d.amc) method to determine if the parse was successful or not :

```
int minutes;
// Attempt the parse here
if(Int32.TryParse(input, out minutes))
{
    // The parse was successful, your value is stored in minutes
}
else 
{
    // The parse was unsuccessful, consider re-prompting the user
}
```